# Scrollbar not appearing in viewport or grid

Tags: layout, extjs, scroll

I have a nested borderlayout within a viewport. The viewport has autoscroll set to true. I have only the west & center regions of the borderlayout

In one of my screens, in the center region, I have a panel which contains 2 grids panels, all of which have autoscroll set to true.

Whenever I minimize the window, no scrollbars appear & it sort of cuts on the bottom grid, just displaying the side border and no bottom.

I've recently changed one screen to have a grid as the main center region and it displays the whole grid but there's no indication to show that it's contained within the screen, it looks as though it's going off screen.

Viewport setup:

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
          autoshow: true,
          autoScroll: true,
          layout   : 'border',
          defaults : {
            frame  : true,
            split  : true
          },
          items : [             
            {
                //accordion view
              title        : 'Navigation',
              region       : 'west',
              collapsible  : false,           
              margins: '100 0 0 0',
              cmargins: '5 5 0 0',
               width: 175,
               minSize: 100,
               maxSize: 150,
               layout: {
                   type: 'accordion',
                   animate: true
               }, ....
  {
                //center region of screen
              xtype  : 'container',
              region : 'center',
              layout : 'fit',
              id     : 'centerRegion',
              margins: '100 0 0 0',
              autoEl : {}                   
            }
```

The grid that gets cut off:

```
var config = {  
                //id: "priorGrid"
                //,
                title: 'Prior Reports '
                ,height: 300
                ,width: 700,
                stripeRows: true
                ,autoScroll: true
                ,tools:[
                        {
                            id:'help',
                            qtip: 'Get Help',
                            handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
                                // whatever
                            }                           

                        }]
                ,store: dataStore
                ,columns:
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the grids parent ( I assume the parent is the center item in the viewport ) to  `autoScroll:true` ?